# MS Graph API - change notifications for /users on AAD, but only some fields

Tags: c#, .net, notifications, microsoft-graph-api

please I would like to ask, if there is way, how to create MS Graph API subscription to /users "collection" in AAD, but we need to be notified only about changes on given fields.

We use Microsoft.Graph package v 5.9.0

If we set `subscription.Resource = "/users"`, then we are getting notifications about any change on the any user of given tenant(s). Problem is that most of the notifications are useless for us, because we do not process those properties. We tried to search for some "filter" of send notifications on AAD side, but only what we found is that we can use
`subscription.Resource = $"/users?$select=GivenName,Surname,MobilePhone,BusinessPhones"`,
but on that we start to get notifications only on GivenName and Surname attributes, but no on any other even it was requested (MobilePhone, BusinessPhones).

Please is there way how achieve our goal - be notified about changes of any user, but only when any of given properties has changed?

Thank you
Petr

Comment: When you set subscription.Resource = "/users", does the response contain data for MobilePhone, BusinessPhones? Which permissions do you use?

Comment: subscription.Resource is set when change notification subscription is being created. Returned created subscription contains exactly same .Resource as was defined in post request - 'var createdSubscription = await graphClient.Subscriptions.PostAsync(subscription);'

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph API does not currently support currently support property level change notification. It only supports resource level change notifications.

Your best solution would be to try use delta queries to track changes to those properties you are interested in. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/delta-query-overview